# Timeout errors can occur when running script

Tags: php, database, shell, web-hosting

The error you're encountering, a timeout error with code 524, is related to the execution time of your script and the database query. Handling a large number of records, such as 120 000 tables, can be resource-intensive and lead to timeouts and also I mentioned script also.

```
<?php
include 'Connection.php';
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from user  where status='1' and newid='0' order by id asc");
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
while($rowu = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
$ref = $rowu['refer'];
 
// Add team_point transactions for the user's referred levels
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
$sql_ref = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '" . $ref . "' AND status = 1";
$result_ref = mysqli_query($con, $sql_ref);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result_ref) > 0) {
$row_ref = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_ref);
$note = ($i == 1) ? 'DIRECTREFERAL' : 'TEAMREFERAL';
  
$queryplan=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `user_plan` where user_id='".$row_ref['id']."'")or die(mysqli_error($con));
$rowplan=mysqli_fetch_array($queryplan);
$plan = ($i == 1) ? $rowplan['plan_id'] : $rowplan['plan_id'];
  
$queryrp = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `plan` where id='" . $rowplan['plan_id'] . "' and `status`='1'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
$rowrp = mysqli_fetch_array($queryrp);
$max_ceiling=$rowrp['max_ceiling'];

$sql1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM newsalarylimit_table where user_id='" . $row_ref['id'] . "' ") or die(mysqli_error($con));
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql1)==0)
 {
$query6 = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `newsalarylimit_table`(`id`,`user_id`, `basic`,`direct`,`team`, `amount`) 
VALUES (NULL,'" . $ref . "','" . $rowrp['ads_watching'] . "','0','0','" . $rowrp['ads_watching'] . "')") or die(mysqli_error($con)); 
 }
 
 
$sqls1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from newsalarylimit_table  WHERE user_id='" . $ref . "'")or die(mysqli_error($con));
$rows1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sqls1);
$basic = $rows1['basic'];
$direct = $rows1['direct'];
$team = $rows1['team'];
$currectsalarylimit = $rows1['amount'];
  
$eligiblereferCountArray = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20];
if ($i >= 1 && $i <= 10) {
$eligiblereferCount = $eligiblereferCountArray[$i];
}
$referCountQuery = mysqli_query($con,"select * from user where refer='".$ref."' and status='1'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
$referCount = mysqli_num_rows($referCountQuery); 
if($referCount>20) {$referCount=20;} else{ $referCount;} 

$cstatus=$refamount=0;
if($max_ceiling >= $currectsalarylimit)
{
if ($i == 1 && $referCount >= $eligiblereferCount) {
$refamount = $rowrp['direct_referral'];
$direct +=  $rowrp['direct_referral'];
}
elseif ($referCount >= $eligiblereferCount && $i >= 2 && $i <= 4) {   
$refamount = $rowrp['team_referral1'];
$team += $rowrp['team_referral1'];
}
elseif ($referCount >= $eligiblereferCount && $i >= 5 && $i <= 7) {   
$team += $rowrp['team_referral2'];
}
elseif ($referCount >= $eligiblereferCount && $i >= 8 && $i <= 10) {   
$refamount = $rowrp['team_referral3'];
$team += $rowrp['team_referral3'];
}
else {
$cstatus = -1;
$direct; 
$team;
}
}
 else
{
$cstatus=-2; 
}
$totalamount = $basic+$direct+$team;
$query = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `newsalarylimit_table` SET `basic`='" . $basic . "',`direct`='" . $direct . "',`team`='" . $team . "',`amount`='" . $totalamount . "'  WHERE  `user_id`='" . $ref . "'") or die(mysqli_error($con)); 
$sql_team = "INSERT INTO `newreferal_transaction`( `refer_id`, `user_id`,`level`, `plan`, `amount`, `description`,`currentdate`,`time`,`cstatus`,`iscoupon`) 
VALUES ('".$rowu['id']."','".$row_ref['id']."','" . $i . "','" .  $plan . "','" . $refamount . "','" . $note . "','" . $row_ref['activatedtime'] . "','" . $row_ref['activatedtime'] . "','" . $cstatus . "','" . $row_ref['iscoupon'] . "')";
mysqli_query($con, $sql_team);
 
$query = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `user` SET `newid`='1' WHERE `id`='" . $row_ref['id'] . "'") or die(mysqli_error($con)); 
$ref = $row_ref['refer'];
} else {
   break;
   }
  }
}
   }
  ?>
 <script>
alert('Transaction Completed Successfully');
 </script>
```

I have tried above code

Comment: If the script takes longer to execute than PHP's configured max execution time limit is set to, you get a timeout message. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php. Do you have a specific question about it? If so, you missed adding it to the post.